# failed to create account with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i tried to do everything correctly and can't seem to find what's wrong here, i even created the project again from scratch but still it doesn't work, but i get the "failed" toast when trying to create an account, i added the internet permission too. i also don't get any error in logcat to show it here, how can this be solved ?

```
public class CreateAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnCreateAcc;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
private FirebaseUser currentUser;

// firestore
private FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

private CollectionReference collectionReference = database.collection("Users");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (currentUser != null) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    };

    btnCreateAcc = findViewById(R.id.create_acct_button);

    btnCreateAcc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etEmail.getText().toString()) &&
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(etPassword.getText().toString()) &&
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(etUserName.getText().toString())) {

                String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                String username = etUserName.getText().toString();

                createUserEmailAccount(email, password, username);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "Please fill in all fields"
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

private void createUserEmailAccount(String email, String password, final String username) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            assert currentUser != null;
                            final String currentUserId = currentUser.getUid();

                            Map<String, String> userObj = new HashMap<>();
                            userObj.put("userId", currentUserId);
                            userObj.put("username", username);

                            collectionReference.add(userObj)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                            documentReference.get()
                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                                            if (Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).exists()) {
                                                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                                                String name = task.getResult()
                                                                        .getString("username");

                                                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this,
                                                                        PostJournalActivity.class);
                                                                intent.putExtra("username", name);
                                                                intent.putExtra("userId", currentUserId);
                                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                            } else {
                                                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "failed"
                                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "failed task"
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "failed on complete"
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "failed else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);

}
}
```

Comment: What is your logcat output?

Comment: Maybe you are getting the "failed" toast in the storage functionality. Put a log or toast right after account creation.

Comment: Have you enabled the Email Provider from Authentication in Firebase?

Comment: Also, have you enabled Firestore?

Comment: @NovoLucas yes i did.

Comment: And your user is getting created in the auth console right?

Comment: @YashKrishan yes the problem was with firestore, i fixed it now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed, the problem was i had  `allow read, write: if false;` in firestore
and it needed to be `allow read, write: if true;`

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted and close the question

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by following good debugging practices.

#### Meaningful error messages

When you encounter an error and wish to send a toast/alert to the user, send something meaningful to inform them *what* went wrong. As an example, instead of "failed" or "failed task", use "failed to upload user data" or "failed to create new user".

Each function will normally return a handful of exception classes that can be used to provide a better toast/alert message. Consulting the documentation for [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#public-taskauthresult-createuserwithemailandpassword-string-email,-string-password) you can see what exceptions are thrown and use `instanceof` to determine the cause of the problem. For example, if `e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException` was `true`, you could toast "failed to create new user: invalid email".

While this seems tedious, it will save head-scratching later when a user encounters a problem and sends you a bug report/email about it. These steps will help you find any issues without needing access to logs for trivial problems such as incorrectly filled forms.

#### Log exceptions

The reason you have no information on what went wrong is because you haven't made use of the exception provided in each `onFailure` handler (`public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { ... }`). These handlers provide you with the exception that caused the problem which you can save to the log using `Log.e("yourActivityName:yourFunctionName", "short message", e)`. You can also use `e.getMessage()` to get information about the thrown error.

In an `onComplete(Task<?> task)` handler, if `task.isSuccessful()` returns `false`, you can find out why it is false by calling `Exception e = task.getException()` and then log it.

#### Fail-fast programming

If you ever find that you have an `if`-`else` pair where the `if` section contains lots more code than the `else` section, it is likely to be a sign that you should flip the condition.

Whilst keeping your code cleaner by using less indentation, it also avoids having to scroll through a long `if` that probably contains more `if` and `else` statements.

For example,

```java
if (!requiredVariable1.isEmpty() && !requiredVariable2.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
    // many (nested) lines of code
    // ...
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "a required variable was empty");
}
```

```java
if (requiredVariable1.isEmpty() || requiredVariable2.isEmpty()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "a required variable was empty");
    return;
}

// ...
// many lines of code
// ...
```

#### Example

As an example of applying these changes, I have made edits to the code you provided applying fail-fast techniques, simplifying error handling, logging exceptions, using `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener` instead of `OnCompleteListener` where appropriate,

```java
private void createUserEmailAccount(String email, String password, final String username) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                assert currentUser != null;
                final String currentUserId = currentUser.getUid();

                Map<String, String> userObj = new HashMap<>();
                userObj.put("userId", currentUserId);
                userObj.put("username", username); // unknown source for variable: username

                collectionReference.add(userObj)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            documentReference.get() // why redownload from database? you could just use values of "userObj"
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                        if (!task.isSuccessful()
                                          || !Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).exists()) {
                                            // show a error message?
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        String name = task.getResult()
                                                .getString("username");

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this,
                                                PostJournalActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("username", name);
                                        intent.putExtra("userId", currentUserId);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "failed to add user data"
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("CreateAccountActivity", "failed to add user data", e); // log error to logcat
                        }
                    });

            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "failed to create user"
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("CreateAccountActivity", "failed to create user", e); // log error to logcat
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is great, will keep it in mind for future coding and questions.